# Replace Match Function is giving undefined error, but it works with replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, responsive-design, jquery-animate

I have the links, and they should scroll to the proper section, however, the main topic headers will not work, unless I change their ids first. Once I do that, it no longer scrolls.

Here is a link to the site (must set browser to under 780px)
http://lookupblue.com/elclimo, notice if you choose a subheading like weddings, the full page will scroll, but if you choose events for example it will not. This is because the id #Events is being used by something else, so instead I need #Events to be replaced with #Section1, before scrolling to the position.

My current error says, can't get top of undefined, which leads me to believe the match or replace is not working.

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
        if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(
                navigator.userAgent)) {

            function backupNavigation_click(clicked_href)

            {

                var abc = clicked_href.substring(clicked_href.lastIndexOf('/') +
                    1);

                if (abc.match("^#")) {

                    $('a').on("click", function(e) {
                        // prevent default state change
                        e.preventDefault();
                        // get href of clicked
                        var abc = $(this).attr('href');
                        // Find last '/' and get everything after
                        abc = abc.substring(abc.lastIndexOf('/') + 1,
                            abc.length);

                        // If '#' found then chop off
                        if (abc.indexOf('#') > -1) {
                            abc = abc.substring(1, abc.length);

                        }


var mapObj = {
   Home:"Section0",
   Events:"Section1",
   Vehicles:"Section2",
Testimonials:"Section3",
Specials:"Section4",
AboutUs:"Section5",
Quotes:"Section6"
};

 abc = abc.replace(/Home|Events|Vehicles|Testimonials|Specials|AboutUs|Quotes/gi, function(matched){
  return mapObj[matched];
});




                        console.log(abc);


                        // Find matching with matching id

                        var pos = $('#' + abc).offset().top;
                        console.log(pos);

                        // Scroll to it
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: pos
                        }, 400);
                    })

                } else {

                    $('a').on("click", function(e) {
                        // prevent default state change
                        e.preventDefault();
                        // get href of clicked
                        var abc = $(this).attr('href');
                        // Find last '/' and get everything after
                        abc = abc.substring(abc.lastIndexOf('/') + 1,
                            abc.length);

                        // If '#' found then chop off
                        if (abc.indexOf('#') > -1) {
                            abc = abc.substring(1, abc.length);
                        }
                        console.log(abc);

                        // Find matching with matching id
                        var pos = $('#' + abc).offset().top;
                        console.log(pos);

                        // Scroll to it
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: pos
                        }, 400);
                    })

                }

            }

        } else {
            if (window.innerWidth > 779) {
                $('head').append(
                    '   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fullPage.js">'
                );
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                    anchors: ['Home', 'Events', 'Vehicles',
                        'Testimonials', 'Specials',
                        'AboutUs', 'Quotes'
                    ],
                    sectionsColor: ['none', 'none', 'none',
                        'none', 'none', 'none', 'none'
                    ],
                    scrollOverflow: true
                });
            });

        }

    </script>
```

The replace code that works, looks like:

```
var str = "I have a cat, a dog, and a goat.";
var mapObj = {
   cat:"dog",
   dog:"goat",
   goat:"cat"

};
str = str.replace(/cat|dog|goat/gi, function(matched){
  return mapObj[matched];
});

alert(str);
```

Comment: can you post the replace code that works as a here? you can put it in a separate code block...,

Comment: @JordanHendrix, I added it at the bottom.

Comment: I see this error when clicking around the page: `Uncaught TypeError: backupNavigation_click is not a function`

Comment: At first glance, it's a really bad idea to run your replace function with the `i` flag when the keys in your `mapObj` are case sensitive. Secondly, you're redeclaring `abc` as a new variable when you write `var abc`. That should be a different variable name, or just leave off the `var`.  That said, I don't really understand the purpose of that replace function in the first place. Shouldn't that line just be `abc = mapObj[abc]`

Comment: As another regex note, `abc.match("^#")` really should be replaced by `/^#/.test(abc)`

Comment: @JordanHendrix I only get, cannot get top of undefined.

Comment: I just clicked the link you posted, in chrome, and opened the console and clicked the headers you have... it happens on every click

Answer (score 0):

I got it, just needed to do the replace function before doing the substring.